# Map a relationship to addrees and person and company

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I have a doubt about how to map a relationship in my problem

I have to entities `person` and `company` they have fields to store the address, so I have a doubt about the best way to map.

Person and company can share the same addrees.

I´m using mysql workbench to gerenate the diagram and make the database.

So what should I do?

Comment: This is the first question ever on stackoverflow about companies and addresses. They should really add a search function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a new entity named `address` and assign this as foreign key constraint in both `person` and `company` table. If the **address** is same, then both `person` and `company` have the same address thru foreign key.

Comment: thanks, so if other company can use also this address?

like `n` companies can use the same address?

Comment: This is correct.  However, there's a gotcha.  If a person moves, and we just update the address, that implies that the company moved to the same new address.  If the person moves, but not the company or vice versa. the updtate process has to create a new entry in the address table.

Comment: @user2283439: yes, it will be permissible by this design. Please note the issue raised by Walter Mitty

Comment: @user2283439 but how can I set on my table to don´t add the same addrres?

Answer (score 0):

Can a person/company have more than one address?
If not, you could place the FK key in person and company table;

```
 Person Table
   AddressId (FK)

 Company Table
   AddressId (FK)
```

or you could have 2 FKs, one to person and one to company in your address table.

```
 Address Table
   PersonId (FK, Nullable)
   CompanyId (FK, Nullable)
```

If yes, you'll need to do a many-many relationship.
You'll need 2 more tables.

```
 PersonToAddress Table
   PersonId  (FK to Person)      
   AddressId (FK to Address)
   *Compound PK (PersonId, AddressId)

 CompanyToAddress Table
   CompanyId  (FK to Company)      
   AddressId (FK to Address)
   *Compound PK (CompanyId, AddressId)
```

Comment: no, the person and company can have only one address, but one address can have `n` companies ou persons